# Is importing only required components per component a good idea in Vue

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js

I was wondering if it is beneficial for performance in Vue to only import necessary dependencies per component or if all dependencies that are used in some components should just be loaded globally? How does Vue compile the components? Is it the case that all of them are loaded anyway when one page of the app is loaded, or are components also loaded on-the-go?

More concrete:

Is it better to do this:

```
<template>
    ... Some template code
</template>

<script>
    import { MdDialog, MdContent, MdButton } from 'vue-material/dist/components'

    export default {
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Or is it better to import these things globally in `app.js`, even if some components only use a fraction of them?

Comment: you should probably look at this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html You should do async loading (if you're using webpack), as it lowers the amount of initial loading (downloads) needed to show your homepage or whatever other page that a user is on. Afterwards, they can just download the necessary pages, rather than downloading your entire app. And I'm pretty sure that a component used in more than one place is generally stored so you're not having repeated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a matter of preference.

It won't have a noticeable impact on performance as the build process handles these multiple imports.

If you chose to import locally you will see where things come from... Otherwise on larger codebase it could lead to a lot of confusion.

Another thing is if you decide to make async component import. If the imports are only used in the dynamically imported component they should come with it's chunk, otherwise if they get imported in more than one component local importing would mean code duplication...

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful :)